# Website design for real time application Socket.io vs Firebase

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, websocket, socket.io

Hello I would like to design a website where there will be many clients connected, rapidly entering numbers. The sever responsibility is to collect all the numbers entered by clients and do some calculation to be displayed on the browser.

I am planning to use NodeJS with express framework as a for the web server. Recently, I have begun to use Socket.io as well.

So my question is whether socket.io is the right choice for this particular design? Will socket.io be able to grab every bits of information client rapidly typed to server? Or Firebase is better? I would like to store the information client typed to server as well and with socket.io I am planning to use MongoDB.